# Automated Updating of a Program via powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, updates

I am trying to updating a software that is company wide. When the update is applied to the server, the client machines recognize they need an update and ask if you wish to update or not. To update, the user would need to run as admin, which is'nt an option in this case.

We would like to automate this process using powershell, using the `Invoke-Command` feature. For the most part, the only thing that the update does is copy new files to the programs folder, which we have achieved with robocopy. However, there is one registry key that needs to be added in multiple locations. There is a setup file that does this, but requires a user (with admin privileges) click a couple buttons, and we want this to be completely automated.

So I guess the short version of my question is, what is the best way to handle the registry changes that `setup.exe` does? It would be nice if there was a way to invoke the script that the executable does.

Comment: You could repackage the new version to a msi or create a script that does the job and run i using SCCM, psexec (and a computer-loop), GPO or startup script so it will run with SYSTEM priviliges.

Comment: I am running a powershell script with administrator commands, which does give me access to the registry, program files and other restricted areas. My problem is that I don't know what registry changes need to happen to make the program run correctly, so I don't know how to program that into a PS Script or .exe or whatever.

Comment: This is an infrastructure administration rather than a programming question, so [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place for it.

Comment: I agree with @AnsgarWiechers  .  As for registry-changes, you could try something like "regshot" to capture before and after or process monitor.

Comment: Thanks, I'd never heard of server fault before. Will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

As for my question, I solved the problem with a slightly diferent approach. (One that should have been tried initially)

When (ProgramName).exe is run, if it sees that it needs updated, it runs a program called (ProgramName).setup.exe with the parameters :
Client="Local folder" server="server location"

These parameters did NOT work from the command line, however, and so I ended up using a powershell script to make a scheduled task that ran (ProgramName).setup.exe with said parameters.

Another huge advantage to this was the fact that I could create an icon that allowed a regular user to run the scheduled task with admin privileges. I couldn't setup a shortcut directly, however, I wrote an AUTO-it Executable that would run the task as admin.

I hope someone can get some level of help out of this post!